# kentico is not able to trim a string, error outOfBoundException

Tags: c#, split, substring, transformation, kentico

I am trying to switch from iframe tag to < a > tag by taking the src of youtube iframe and use it as a src for < a> tag, I have already put the video sources as a large string in the page form and split it to smaller parts by this char '|' so each < a> tag will know which src index he'll have to reference. my problem is that I want to take the image of youtube video by using this format:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg
```

from the split string, so to get this image i am trying to resplit the source string , to get the video Id (and therefore get the video image) below is my code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string [] values = ImageFieldValues.Split('|');
    if (values.Length != 0) { 
    foreach (string source in values)
    {

        litCon.Text = "<a name='testiFrame' data-fancybox-type='iframe' id='runtimeIFrame' class='col-xs-3 various fancybox.iframe' style='margin-bottom: 10px;float: right;'  href='" + source+ "'><img id='iframeImage' src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ source.Substring(26) + "/hqdefault.jpg'/></a>";
        AddToDivImages.Controls.Add(litCon);


    }
    }
}
```

this is a custom control used within a transformation in kentico project, video sources are loading fine, the only problem is with source.substring(26), it is returning an error saying that index is out of boundaries, it is only working for index (0), any number larger than zero will return the same error, I also tried to trim, split, Remove... its like it is taking the whole string as one block, here is a screenshot for the event log in kentico
[Event Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKvZO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the initial value of `ImageFieldValues`, it's hard to say why it isn't working.  Could it be that you have an empty string (created by an additional pipe at the end of the string)?  Try using the overload for `Split` that removes empty entries:

```
ImageFieldValues.Split(new[] { "|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

---

From the above, I'm assuming that `ImageFieldValues` looks something like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ|https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY
```

Rather than using substrings, you might want to try using a regular expression.  I had a little look and you should be able to achieve what you're with the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pattern = "watch\\?v=(?<code>[A-Za-z0-9_]*)";

    string [] values = ImageFieldValues.Split('|');
    if (values.Length != 0) { 
    foreach (var source in values)
    {
        Match match = Regex.Match(source, pattern);

        litCon.Text = "<a name='testiFrame' data-fancybox-type='iframe' id='runtimeIFrame' class='col-xs-3 various fancybox.iframe' style='margin-bottom: 10px;float: right;'  href='" + source + "'><img id='iframeImage' src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ match.Groups["code"].Value + "/hqdefault.jpg'/></a>";
        AddToDivImages.Controls.Add(litCon);
    }
}
```

This removes the reliance on the index you're using for `source.Substring`, which will protect you if the URL structure varies.  You can find a breakdown of the pattern here if you're not familiar with regular expressions: https://regex101.com/r/3Y0ZNY/1